# Get Message-ID from Swift Mailer callback function Laravel Error

Tags: php, laravel, email

I have been stuck in this for quite a while now. I am trying to extract messageID of an email through a callback function and store in DB for later use. I simulated the same conditions in a gmail based server and it works. But I don't think the email server has to do with anything. Here is my mailable class where I try to extract the messageID:

```
<?php

namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use App\EmailLog;
use App\EmailLogDetail;

class GenericSendEmailMailable extends Mailable
{
    //use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */

    private $applicationTemplate;
    public $subject;
    private $data;
    private $emailLogId;

    public function __construct(String $applicationTemplate,Array $data,String $subject, $emailLogId)
    {
        //
        $this->applicationTemplate = $applicationTemplate;
        $this->data = $data;
        $this->subject = $subject;
        $this->emailLogId = $emailLogId;
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
        $emailLogId = $this->emailLogId;
        $view = $this->applicationTemplate;
        $data = $this->data;
        $subject = $this->subject;
        return $this->subject($subject)
                    ->view($view,$data)
                    ->withSwiftMessage(function ($message) use ($emailLogId){
                        $emailLog = EmailLog::where('id', $emailLogId)->first();
                        if(isset($emailLog->email_log_details)){
                            foreach($emailLog->email_log_details as $emailLogDetail){
                                $emailLogDetail->message_id = $message->getId();
                                $emailLogDetail->save();
                            }
                        }
                    });
    }
}
```

Here, the $message->getId(); should be working fine but its not cause when I send mail and check the DB, the message Id is not stored. By the way, the email send operation is dispatched as a job. Any ideas as to why this is not working?

Comment: check the logs in storage/log/laravel.log

Answer (score 0):

If anybody is interested in the future, this was due to the heavy processing inside the job. I was facing an execution timeout. I did two things, first I did any trivial processing before dispatching the job rather than in the job itself. And finally I increased the timeout by adding

```
public $timeout = 300;
```

in the job class. Also, I increased the "retry_after" in the driver I was using to just a bit more than the actual timeout (320 in my case).
The best way to identify the problem for a queue is to observe the worker.log file and determine whether any jobs failed or not. If failed, the reason (or exception) can be caught by creating a failed_jobs table in your database.